# Not working adapting menu and misplaced placeholder search

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Not working adapting menu and misplaced placeholder search.
I'm trying to make an adaptive menu and ran into some problem.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">FlipKips</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggler="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Telegram</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Discord</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form action="" class="d-flex">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="form-control mr-2">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you post some CSS

Comment: "Problem" and "misplaced" don't tell us what you want. Please see [ask], then revise to be more clear.